# ApplicationContext in BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-context

I have an Application class like this:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
}
```

It is registered in the Manifest:

```
    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    ... 

    </application>
```

I use this Application class for keeping Dagger components etc.

Now I have a BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent){

       MyApplication myApplication = (MyApplication) context.getApplicationContext();           
    }
}
```

It is registered in the Manifest as a [InstallReferrerReceiver](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tagmanager/InstallReferrerReceiver):

```
    <receiver
        android:name="my.package.MyReceiver"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

As you can see I cast the application context to my Application class, which works fine in Activities etc. and also usually here.

Via Crashlytics though I receive exception:

```
Unable to start receiver my.package.BroadcastReceiver: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to my.package.MyApplication
```

My question being: am I *not* guaranteed to receive my Application object as the application Context in a BroadcastReceiver?

Comment: That should work fine. Are there any commonalities between the devices reporting this crash? Also, is there anything unusual about the `<receiver>` element (e.g., you are using `android:process`) or how the broadcast is being sent?

Comment: I think you are not guaranteed to have access to your application in your `BroadcastReceiver` (I'm looking for the source). Can you check `if (context.getApplicationContext() instanceof MyApplication)` ?

Comment: @CommonsWare Sorry, that was probably important to add, I've added the manifest entry for the receiver.

Comment: @ThomasRoulin Yes of course I could check that, but in the end I need to be guaranteed somehow to have *my* Application, else I have to work around that.

Comment: That `<receiver>` looks nice and boring. :-) AFAIK, you should be getting a `MyApplication`. Test this yourself (e.g., use `adb shell am` to send a matching broadcast) and see if it works. If it does, again, look for commonalities in the devices reporting this crash.

Comment: I might be wrong, I can't find anything to support what I said. Looks like I could have been misleading you, sorry.

@CommonsWare seems to be right, everything looks fine if you are guaranteed to have your application from `.getApplicationContext()` 

Notify us if you find something

Comment: Only received the exception once as far as I can see, one unsuspicious Samsung (of course) device, real device, not rooted. 
Maybe one of those freak things that only happen once a decade. 
I will just assume I can get MY application context, see if it occurs again. 
Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the implementation of ActivityThread.handleReceiver you'll see that the BroadcastReceiver.onReceived is invoked by passing ContextImpl.getReceiverRestrictedContext() to it. The context returned by this call doesn't actually wrap getApplicationContext so ti will be called on ContextImpl. Now if you look at ContextImpl.getApplicationContext() you'll see something like this

```
@Override
public Context getApplicationContext() {
    return (mPackageInfo != null) ? mPackageInfo.getApplication() : 
        mMainThread.getApplication();
}
```

If you look at the last branch of the ternary operator you'll see that it will call back to `ActivityThread.getApplication()` which will return it's `mInitialApplication` member. `mInitialApplication` is initialized by invoking `LoadedApk.makeApplication()` which has a boolean parameter : `forceDefaultAppClass`. If set to true `android.app.Application` will instantiated instead the application defined in your manifest.

Based on AOSP source this happens when for e.g.:

> If the app is being launched for full backup or restore, bring it up
>   in a restricted environment with the base application class.